# How to read *.journal files?

Tags: fedora, dmesg, systemd-journald

I want to see the previous dmesg log before the reboot. In previous versions of fedora, It used to be in `/var/log/messages`. But from Fedora 20, it's being stored through `systemd` i.e. `journalctl`.

I've a directory `/var/log/journal`. It has many files and all of them having extension as `.journal`. I tried to open them with `gedit`. But couldn't succeed. I tried with notepad++. It's showing unreadable data as if a binary file.  How to read them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Borrowed from [this answer:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200107/377345)

```
journalctl --file
```

e.g.

```
journalctl --file /path/to/some/file.journal
```

As indicated in that answer, these logs are regularly rotated, and may not stretch back as far as you might hope.

Comment: even with sudo I get `Failed to open files: Bad message`

Comment: It's possible the journal files have become corrupted or unreadble.

Comment: how about reading on a non-systemd box? or non-linux box?

Comment: @ccpizza there's a python module that can parse these files, ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331116/reading-systemd-journal-from-python-script 

I'd guess other languages may have similar tools as well.