# How to detect and clean up junk journal files?

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

One of our Ubuntu 18.04 hosts was caught with 12 GB of `*.journal` files, far more than intended. Attempting to find out if they were worth keeping, I ran

```
journalctl --file $f
```

on each file older than today; which always resulted in either `Failed to open files` or `--- No entries ---`.

Am I correct to conclude that such files are junk and can be discarded?

If they are, why do they exist? What is a supported way to clean them up? Is it worthwhile to regularly check systems for their existence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all Journal is a logging system and is part of `systemd`. Their existence is crucial when you need to know what happened.

As mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200107/360892), `journalctl --file` isn't that usable.

> As the journal files are rotated periodically, this form is not really usable for viewing complete journals.

Now, whether you consider the files useless, that's for you to decide. Normally, too old logs are not worth keeping and you could delete them.

To do that, is best to use `journalctl` itself and its utility vacuum. For instance you can use

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=3weeks
```

to delete all journal files that are more than 3 weeks old.

For more info check the **man page** with `man journalctl`.

> **--vacuum-size=, --vacuum-time=, --vacuum-files=**
>
> Removes the oldest archived journal files until the disk space they
> use falls below the specified size (specified with the usual "K", "M",
> "G" and "T" suffixes), or all archived journal files contain no data
> older than the specified timespan (specified with the usual "s", "m",
> "h", "days", "months", "weeks" and "years" suffixes), or no more than
> the specified number of separate journal files remain. Note that
> running --vacuum-size= has only an indirect effect on the output shown
> by --disk-usage, as the latter includes active journal files, while
> the vacuuming operation only operates on archived journal files.
> Similarly, --vacuum-files= might not actually reduce the number of
> journal files to below the specified number, as it will not remove
> active journal files.

Also, I don't believe its worthwhile to periodically check this. Best thing you can do is set an upper limit by uncommenting and changing the following in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

For example:

```
SystemMaxUse=4G
```

Then restart the service. `sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald`.

Use `man journald.conf` for more information.

---

**Edit**:

As explained by @reinierpost

> This question is not about regular old logs, it is about old logfiles
> that do not appear to contain any logs at all (but they still occupy 8
> MB each).

Try running `journalctl --verify`. If files don't pass then the journal is corrupted and you should restart the service.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

That should fix the problem for logs going forward.

As for why this happened in the first place, I don't know and its not easy to figure out. And yes, corrupted files are probably junk. You could try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457902/360892) for a clean slate.

Comment: `SystemMaxUse` is and was set to `250M`; clearly, that doesn't always work. Maybe `systemd-journald` hadn't been restarted since it was set, I didn't check that. I didn't try the vacuuming utility. This question is not about regular old logs, it is about old logfiles that do not appear to contain any logs at all (but they still occupy 8 MB each). If I understand correctly, `journalctl --file` should show log entries in old rotated logs if any entries are in there.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it, you should restart the service for the changes to take effect. As for the logs try running `journalctl --verify`. If files don't pass then the journal is corrupted and you should restart the service. That should fix the problem for logs going forward. As for why this happened in the first place, I don't know and its not easy to figure out. And yes, corrupted files are probably junk. You could try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457902/360892) for a clean slate. If that answers your question please let me know, so I can update the answer.

Comment: I've removed the files, so I cannot try it anymore, but I will if it reoccurs, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar. On one of my Ubuntu 22.04 machines I had 81G of files in `/var/log/journal` going back 3 years. Actual log data shown by `journalctl --utc --no-pager | head` goes back about 6 days. My `journald.conf` file used all default (sane) values. I started checking other VMs and found similar issues.

I tried:

- Set `SystemMaxUse=10G` and restart systemd-journald
- Set `RuntimeMaxUse=10G` and restart systemd-journald
- Set `SystemMaxFileSize=1G` and SystemMaxFiles=30 and restart systemd-journald
- Set `MaxFileSec=1month` and restart systemd-journald

None of these settings removed any of the old log files from `/var/log/journal`. I also tried:

- `journalctl --flush --rotate`
- `journalctl --rotate --vacuum-time=10days`

All of the old files were still there.

`journalctl --disk-usage` claims that journald is only using 496M.

`journalctl --verify` showed every check as "passed" but only checked a single subdirectory of `/var/log/journal`. I assume that all of the other directories were orphaned by journald but they go right up to the current date, so this is an on-going issue.

I ended up working around the problem by setting `MaxFileSec=1month` (which is supposed to be the default setting) and adding a daily cron job with `find /var/log/journal -mtime +45 -delete` in it to delete any junk that journald is supposed to delete but doesn't.